# jQuery "autocomplete" doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsf-2, autocomplete

The JQuery autocomplete code seems correct, but, does not work.

The code seems simple enough,  and I did not see any javascript errors using "Developer tools" in IE8, or the "firebug" tool in FireFox...

But, nothing "drops down" from the listbox when a letter (e.g., "a")  is typed into the input field...

Please let me know if you can see anything amiss.  I apparently am not "seeing the forest for the trees" at this point.

**Here is the snippet from the definition of the JSF "Composite Component"...**

```
    <!-- INTERFACE -->
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="idpref" required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="items" required="true"/>
</cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>

    <!-- here is the input field -->
    <h:inputText type="text" id="#{cc.attrs.idpref}"/>

    <!-- here is the javascript -->
    <h:outputScript     library="js"        name="jquery-1.7.2.js" />
    <h:outputScript     library="js"        name="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
        jq(document).ready(function()
        {
            jq(function()
            {
                var list = #{cc.attrs.items};
                var id = "#{cc.attrs.idpref}";
                var prependedid = jq('input[id$="' + id + '"]').attr("id");
                var comboid = "#" + prependedid;

                jq(comboid).autocomplete({
                    source: list
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
</cc:implementation>
```

**Here is snippet of view tag contents from the page where the above composite component is used...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:util="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/util"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <title>testx</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
        </h:head>
        <h:body prependid="false">
            <h:form id="form1" prependId="false">
                <util:autoComplete prependId="false"
                                   idpref="aaa"
                                   items="#{refDataController.data}" />
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

**Here is the backend java snippet...**

```
    package aaa.bbb.ccc.war;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component("refDataController")
    @Scope("request")
        public class RefDataController
        {
            public RefDataController()
            {
            }
            private List data = Arrays.asList    ("\"Aman\"", "\"Albela\"", "\"Ali\"", "\"Ankit\"", "\"Azam\"", "\"Aryan\"");
            public List getData()
            {
                return data;
            }
        }
```

Thank you for any assistance!

sd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Seems that there were a combination of two issues (i.e., as a jquery newby)...**

**issue#1**. A somewhat embarrassing oversight (ala, "*is your PC plugged in?*")... I was setting autocomplete function's "minLength" parameter value to 3, and not typing a minimum of 3 characters, so no list was being displayed when initially testing (I removed this parameter and am using the default minimum length of 1, for now)

**issue#2**. The primary issue, however, was that I did not understand the problems that the jquery selector has with the JSF colon (":") character.   I solved this with by using one of two workarounds (after googling the info, etc):

(note: in these snippets, "***#{cc.attrs.idpref}***" is the JSF "***composite component***" attribute is am using to specify element id... FWIW, in this case the value happens to be "***aaa***")

***workaround#1***:

```
//get the full id value of the element whose "id ends with" aaa...
var id = jq('input[id$="' + "#{cc.attrs.idpref}" + '"]').attr("id");
//"escape" the colon character so that jquery will not be confused...
id = id.replace(/:/g,"\\:");
//used escaped id value in the selector...
jq("input#" + id).autocomplete({
   source: list
});
```

***workaround#2***:

```
//start with the **unprepended** id value specified in the composite component  attribute...
var id = "#{cc.attrs.idpref}";
// use the "id ends with" aaa selector with the autocomplete function... 
jq('input[id$="' + "#{cc.attrs.idpref}" + '"]').autocomplete({
   source: list
});
```

Thanks for all your collective reponses!

sd

Answer (score 0):

Is that code called at all? This piece of code seems a bit redundant. I doubt if the function passed to the inner `jq` is ever called. If indeed it isn't, the autocomplete is never initialized. You can verify by adding breakpoints or just place an alert before and after the call to `jq(comboid).autocomplete` If you get the two alerts, then the line will be executed as well (may it be with the wrong element).

```
jq(document).ready(function()
{
   jq(function()
   ....
```

Comment: I'll put in the 2 alerts before and after "jq(comboid).autocomplete" ...--get back to you in a moment. thanks

Comment: I added alert before and after the "autocomplete" and both displayed when entering or refreshing the page.

Comment: It's indeed a strange and unnecessary approach, but it works. Further, the `prependedid` and `comboid` variable assignment approaches are also strange and unnecessary. Why don't you just use `jq('input[id$="' + id + '"]').autocomplete(...)` directly?

Comment: I removed the "jq(function()", and get the same results - both alerts display.  I guess I'll leave them out, then.  Still not getting any "dropdown" list

Comment: And the combo element is found? What does `jq(comboid).length` return? It should be 1.

Comment: Thank you BalusC. -I'll try your suggestion, and let you know what happens in a moment or so, thanks!...  (The "strange and unnessary" is due to a combination of "running out of options to try", and being a somewhat inexperienced jquery user, I suppose.)

Comment: Been there, done that. Sometimes it's best to start from scratch with a new, empty file until you get it working. If you compare the failing page and the working test page, you may get surprising results (things you never thought you would overlook. ;))

Comment: ...also, JSF "prepends" ids from containing elements, and I need to isolate the id of the element required for the autocomplete.

Comment: the input element (when viewing source) looks like this:  "<input id="j_idt7:aaa" type="text" name="j_idt7:aaa" />".  Note the "id".  So, my thinking was to make certain that I used this value in the selector (using "comboid").   The "comboid" variable resolves to the "id" selector value I think is required for the autocomplete:  "#j_idt7:aaa".   Unfortunately, its still not working...  I'm wondering whether when using a JSF 2.x "composite component" if there are other considerations that I am unaware of, etc

Comment: Could the fact that the "id" and "name" both have the same value cause this sort of issue?  (more shots in the dark)

Comment: No, but note that the id must be unique. You are not allowed to have another element with the same id. It's no problem that the same (or another) element has the same name.

Comment: thanks... fyi - "alert("AFTER: jq(comboid)autocomplete...jq(comboid).length:" + jq(comboid).length );"  yields:  0.   I dont know what this means about the selector... The "id" is I'm using appears correct.  I am adding the hash (#) symbol to the beginning, etc

Comment: I don't have enough information to answer that. I cannot see the id in your current code, but anyway, you've found a cause: The code may be right, but the selector doesn't match an element.